# Custom report translation in OpenERP

Tags: report, openerp-7

Basically all the reports are changed language as per the customer language in OpenERP 7.0. But I have customized a new accounting report as same as default accounting(invoice) report.
While printing my custom report that is not translating based on customer language. Please help to solve this. I am trying this more than two days and not yet any solution.

Note: I have also used setLang function in my report.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the best solution is to add the i18n folder to your custom addon. In there you add the appropriate .po file and the trick is done.

Remember to add:

- folder called i18n

In there

- file module_name.pot
- file language.po (example it.po)

Answer (score 0):

Salam !

just make [[ setLang('code_lang*') ]] up report

- example for french country fr_FR

I hop that help you